# Forgotten SEED, Could you help me?

Tags: seed

I have a problem, when i created my new wallet, so i took a photo my seed to my mobile, that then i will write to my notebook. But next day, my mobile shuted down and i must to reset it, what my seed has been deleted. 
Is it possible, how to refresh my seed or gain it back?

Do you know to help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Does the wallet that produced the seed still work, or are you looking for the seed in order to restore the wallet?

Comment: You could also try file recovery software on your phone to see if the image is still there. What software did you use to create the seed?

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to write down your seed phrase with pen and paper (or some other permanent, real-world method of recording it), it is a BIG security risk to store it digitally. Do not ever take a photo of your seed phrase again!

Unfortunately, if you reset your phone and your photos were deleted , and that was the only copy of the seed (I'm assuming no cloud backup), then you may have lost your bitcoins. Your only hope is to somehow recover the deleted photo from your phone, but this may be very difficult/impossible to do.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you didn't have a significant amount of bitcoins on that wallet.  Check if you had auto backups to a cloud service (Google Photos/Dropbox/iCloud).  If not rather than asking here, look into how to restore data from a mobile phone. It may be possible, I recommend not playing with your phone until you know how you will proceed.  Alternatively, there are professional services that may have better luck.

Good luck!